# Using an index from a list as a variable in a plot title

Tags: r, list, plot

I have created a graphing function:

```
plotfun = function(dat, pos, tetrad.name=NULL, snp.cols=c("blue", "red", "lightgray")){
    plot(1,1, type="n", xlim=c(min(pos), max(pos)), ylim=c(0.75,4.25), yaxt="n", xaxt="n", main=paste("CCT6 -",tetrad.name), xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", cex=.75)
    abline(h=1:4, lty="dotted")
    tmpnull = sapply(1:4, function(n) points(pos, rep((4:1)[n],length(pos)), col=snp.cols[dat[n,]], pch=16))
    mtext(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), side=2, line=0.5, at=4:1, las=1, cex=.5)
}
```

I am trying to use this graphing function to graph a subset of matrices that I have indexed from a larger list (`x` in this example). I am using `sapply` to graph all of the matrices individually:

```
sapply(1:69, function(n) plotfun(dat=matrix.transform(x[[n]]), pos=cct6.pos, tetrad.name= n ))
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to have the plot title read as the list number attached to each matrix. Instead, it labels them `1:69`, losing the information that from the indexed input. For example if the first input is `cct6[[35]]` I'd like the plot title to read `"CCT6-35"` not `"CCT6-1"`

Sorry if this is a basic question. I'm just stuck on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `main= ...` argument a line in the plot call within 'plotfun' with this snippet:

```
main=bquote("CCT6-*.(tetrad.name))
```

When I tried this with a simple test case I found that the lazy evaluation aspect resulted in (not an error but a failure to properly label the plots. Adding a force() cal fixed that issue. Compare these two:

```
for(n in 1:2) plot(1,1,main=bquote("N="*.(n)))

for(n in 1:2) {force(n); plot(1,1,main=bquote("N="*.(n)))}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little. Ive tried to insert this into both the  plotfun and `sapply` functions and have not had success. I get both errors and incomplete code lines when Ive tried to enter it.

Comment: That isnt working for me. When I enter it in exactly as above, I get an error message saying: 

`Error: unexpected string constant in:
"plotfun = function(dat, pos, tetrad.name=NULL, snp.cols=c("blue", "red", "lightgray")){
        plot(1,1, type="n", xlim=c(min(pos), max(pos)), ylim=c(0.75,4.25), yaxt="n", xaxt="n", main=bquote("CCT6-*.(tetrad.name)), xlab="", ylab=""`

Comment: @SamGlobus -- Try this instead: `main = paste("CCT6", bquote(.(tetrad.name)), sep="-")`.